# Visual Studio - ntoskrnl.exe cannot be found

Tags: c, windows, dll, kernel, wdm

I'm writing a Windows DLL and I need some functions from wdm.h. I'm linking with ntoskrnl.lib and it compiles just find with no warnings or errors and when it runs the application, it says cannot find ntoskrnl.exe. However, that EXE is in my C:\Windows\System32 folder. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The error is confusing. It doesn't mean it can't find the file, it means it can't load it. You can't load ntoskrnl.exe in usermode because it is a kernel mode DLL. In fact it is the kernel. Loading it again doesn't make any sense. wdm.h is not meant to be included by user mode components.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. However, I have the WDK from Windows and I set my project type as a DLL the commincates with Kernel Drivers. I must need to add something in order to use ntoskrnl.exe. Would you happen to know what I need to do?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  What makes you think that you need to use ntoskrnl.exe in order to do it?

Comment: I'm making a kernel (audio) streaming driver. I need it for some IO stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I have fixed the problem. Then I got a warning that said .crt section exists. I found out I can't use the CRT library when I'm in kernel mode. So I fixed that. Now I have one question. If I create this driver in kernel mode, will I be able to access it with a C/C++ program in user mode?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think part of my problem is I need to research Windows drivers a little more.

Comment: Sounds sensible.  :-) Note that some kinds of drivers are radically different to others; the links above are applicable to generic drivers but might not necessarily apply to your particular scenario.

Comment: Well glancing over them it looks like pretty useful information.